# Time Travel & The Girl Who Leapt Through Time

Tags: plot-explanation, time-travel, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

I just watched the movie *The Girl Who Leapt Through Time* and it was beautiful. Since it's a movie with a concept of Time travel and loops questions might come up.

In the movie nearly towards the end it is revealed that Chiaki came from the future for that painting and eventually falls in love with Makoto.

After that when Chiaki leaves that present World or maybe just disappeared a few girls are show gossiping about Chiaki marrying a girl older in age.

Then Makoto leaps through time one last time to change things again and jumps in a time where Chiaki hasn't yet revealed that he came from future and Makota wanted him to express his feelings, finally Chiaki comes near her and whispers "I will meet you again".

So my question is, since Makota lives in the past relative to Chiaki as he came from the future, Makota is actually older than him, and both promises each other to meet in the future and possibly marry. It is not yet understood by me that how come those girls knew that Chiaki married a girl older in age while it was still the present day and not future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I thought it was a great movie too.

In that scene where the girls are gossiping, there are many random things they are saying about Chiaki's disappearance. One of the girls says "Apparently he was in debt and the mob was after him". The other asks "It's not something like his parents are getting a divorce?". Then the other girl says "Well I heard he's marrying an older woman because he got her pregnant".

These are just simple gossip the girls are involved in and doesn't actually refer to a possible future time when Chiaki meets Makota. In any case, Chiaki is shown to be a decent guy and not a "player", he wouldn't get Makota pregnant and then marry her as a consequence :).

Even the guys are gossiping about Chiaki's disappearance. One of them says "I heard he stabbed some guy". The other says "I heard he beat him up with a baseball bat". Basically, the whole school is talking and coming up with reasons for his disappearance.

Comment: That's what I also thought, random gossiping, but as being a movie about time-travel I had a feeling that it has to be somehow related to the plot. Haha! 

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I never saw it that way, but the "getting her pregnant" part sort of gives away the baseless rumors. If you liked the anime, you should also check out Time Traveler, this was a live action movie was based on the same theme, not with so many time jumps though. The voice of Makota has done the lead role :).